# The difference between 'will' and 'will be'

Tags: future, will-be-going

What's the difference between these two sentences?

1) The parcel will be delivered in September.
2) The parcel will be delivering in September.

I highly doubt that the second sentence is grammatically incorrect. But before expressing my thought, anyone has any idea?

Comment: Your title doesn’t match the body of your question here – both your sentences contain _will be_, and the fact that both are future constructions seems irrelevant to the actual question. What you really seem to be asking is what the difference is between **active** and **passive**, but that question is very broad and not well-suited to a StackExchange site. I would suggest that you first read up on what the active and passive voices are in your grammar reference of choice; that should actually answer your question for you.

Answer (score -1):

The parcel is the object of the sentence, so 'will be delivered' is correct. The second example implies the parcel itself will be performing the delivery - and so is complete nonsense, and grammatically incorrect.

Comment: This is not correct, I’m afraid. The parcel is the subject in both sentences, though it is the _patient_ (rather than the _agent_) in the first, which is a passive construction. The second sentence is logically nonsensical, but grammatically there’s nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

'The parcel' is the *subject* in both sentences, so only **version 1** is correct, since it uses the verb 'to deliver' in *passive voice*. 'Will be delivering' would only make sense if combined e. g. with 'couriers' who deliver parcels (in version 2 'parcel delivers' something).